# access the database from static pages in cakephp1.3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

i am making a website using cakephp 1.3,i hav made a static page where i want to access some data from the database.i tried using the find() but i was not able to access it.i tried putting a function in the pages controller and passing the data to the static page but again i couldn't.
here is what i tried in pages controller

```
 function subjects(){
$subjects = $this->Subject->find("all");

$this->set('subjects', $subjects );
```

}

is there a way to access the database from thr static page in cake php?
if yes please let me know...

Comment: If the page uses data from the `Subject` model, why not put it in the subjects controller?

Comment: i wrote subject for giving an example.act i hav a static page called admin where i want to display the subjects from the db

Comment: It's not a static page if you display data from database. If you just put the page in the subjects controller the problem is solved.

Comment: Does the data you want from the database have an associated model / controller?

Answer (score 0):

In your `PagesController` add a property like this:

```
public $uses = array('Subject');
```

Although if your page is loading dynamic data it isn't static anymore. :)

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare PagesController::$uses in F:\xampp\htdocs\fbf\app\pages_controller.php on line 57

Comment: Sounds like you've already got a `$uses` property.  If you do, stick 'Subject' into that.

Comment: dheeraj, if you want help with something not related to this, create another question and **show code**.  Nobody can help you if the only thing we have to work with is "I got an error"

Answer (score 0):

you can - although not recommended - use

```
$records = ClassRegistry::init('Modelname')->find('all', ...);
```

in your static pages

it is a quick and dirty solution if no other solution fits your needs